# Vaadin clicklistener / buttonclick throws exception without click

Tags: java, vaadin, onclicklistener, buttonclick, clicklistener

I'm using Vaadin and it seems that the Clicklistener of my Button recognizes a click where no click is.

When I load the page in my browser, I get an error message, TreeTaggerException is fired, because the List "selectedWords" is empty.

```
buildDic = new Button();
buildDic.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
      public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
      Dictionary dic1 = new Dictionary();                       
                try {
                    dic1.generateDictionary("D:/....txt", selectedWords, 5, 5, 6);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TreeTaggerException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

Where does the event come from, or where is my mistake?

Comment: Did you check the whole stacktrace to see where it originated from, and if it's indeed the `ClickListener` to blame or something else?

Comment: Yes, I had a look, an in my opionion its exactl the clicklistener. If I comment out the try-catch, everything is fine. The excepation itself is absolutely ok, because of the empty list (the list is filled when the user does a selection on the page). Here is the stacktrace: http://abload.de/img/zwischenablage03hvset.jpg

Comment: UPDATE: It seems its an noClassDefFoundError. But the path to the classfile is correct. AND: this is the execution with/in vaadin. If I execute this "generateDictionary" method from another Main class with Main method...everything is fine, no error.

Comment: This is a web-app classpath issue. Depending on how you build and run your app, most likely that library is not packaged/published. We would need to know how you're doing the packaging and execution, maven, spring-boot, eclipse, etc

Comment: Ah, tank you. I'm working with eclipse Mars, no Maven anywhere. At the moment I'm running it on a locol Tomcat 8.0. There's also a connection to a local mysql server (via XAMPP)...if this is neccessary to know. Do you need anymore information?

Comment: You have to check how you generate the war that is deployed in your tomcat installation, making sure all of the dependencies are being packaged.

Comment: Do you know where I can change setting for war file generation? Please consider: I do not export and generate a war file which I put in the tomcat folder. I'm still in my developement environment, I start Tomcat by clicking the green arrow an the project is running and available locally. But maybe eclipse is alsp generating the war automatically and puts it in the tomcat folder too.